# Nautilus crashes after Ubuntu Tweak Package Cleaner

Tags: nautilus

Few days ago I started having some problems with nautilus.

Basically when I'm trying to get into a folder it crashes. It's not happening all the time, but in 85% it does... Sometimes, after the crash all my desktop icons are also gone.

The only thing that I think causes this is Ubuntu Tweak - I'm not sure, but the issues started after I did the Package cleaner from Ubuntu Tweaks...

Any ideas?

------- EDIT 2 - IMPORTANT !!! ----------

It seems I fixed this problem doing these:

1) I uninstall this nautilus script - http://mundogeek.net/nautilus-scripts/#nautilus-send-gmail
2) I installed nautilus elementary

So far is back to normal... If anything bad happens again I will come back!

-------- EDIT 1 ----------

First time, after running the command (nautilus --quit; nautilus --no-desktop) 3 times all the system crashed (except the mouse, I could move the mouse).

After restart I run it and obtain this:

> ----- Initializing nautilus-gdu extension Initializing
>   nautilus-dropbox 0.6.7
>   (nautilus:2966): GConf-CRITICAL **:
>   gconf_value_free: assertion `value !=
>   NULL' failed (nautilus:2966):
>   GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free:
>   assertion`value != NULL' failed
>   Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net
>   usershare info" but it failed: 'net
>   usershare' returned error 255: net
>   usershare: cannot open usershare
>   directory /var/lib/samba/usershares.
>   Error No such file or directory 
>   Please ask your system administrator
>   to enable user sharing.

and then this:

> cristi@cris-laptop:~$ nautilus --quit;
>   nautilus --no-desktop (nautilus:3810):
>   Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Error while
>   sending message: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the
>   remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was
>   broken.

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using?Create a new user and see if that user has the same problem?This will help us to find the problem.

Comment: I am using 11.04 - it's a good idea to create a different user. I will try and see what happens. Thank you

Comment: Actually I'm using 10.10 - I just saw that in my About Ubuntu is written "You are using Ubuntu 11.04 - the Natty Narwhal - released in April 2011 and supported until October 2012." - don't know why though...

Comment: That is a bug,ignore it.

Comment: @ka7anax Now that you've figured out the problem post it as a seperate answer and accept it (it makes you wait a while before you can do that though), that is the equivalent of [fixed].

Comment: I have used scripts in nautilus. Eventually nautilus starts to leak memory. So I have to disable it. I think, using scripts in nautilus is not a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I fixed this problem doing these:

1) I uninstall this nautilus script - http://mundogeek.net/nautilus-scripts/#nautilus-send-gmail

2) I removed a set of nautilus scripts previously installed - [this pack](http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2007/09/125-nautilus-scripts-to-simplify.html)

3) I installed nautilus elementary

I don't know which onow everything is back to normal

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I recommend no to use nautilus scripts, they leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen crashes with specific kinds of broken files, extentions and a couple of other querks.

Can you run nautilus from the command line like so, try it a few times if it fails the first time:

```
nautilus --quit; nautilus --no-desktop
```

Once you have nautilus running from command line without returning, browse around your filesystem until it crashes. Report back in your original question what the errors and warnings are.